# Why does style TargetType="Window" not work when set from App.xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window

I'm creating a simple WPF project in VS2013 and I want to apply properties to my main Window. I set them in my `App.xaml` file like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Window">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF2D2D30" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

The problem is that nothing happens. When I change the `TargetType` to Grid however, the setter property works just fine. Why does this happen?

Comment: If you have specified Background property on Window explicitly, it will override the style property.

Comment: I haven't set any Background property on the window explicitly. The <Window> only sets allowstransparency to true and windowstyle to none...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is necessary to add construction in `Window`:

```
Style="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}"
```

`Window` in XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WindowStyleHelp.MainWindow"
        Style="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}"
        ...>
```

Or define `Style` in resources like this:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyWpfApplication"

<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF2D2D30"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 5):

Answering for this question "Why does it not works".

The reason why the Target type is not applied to your Window is because, you are using a derived type of a window with name "MainWindow". So in your style resource you have to set the target type as the derived type (MainWindow). By doing so it will be applied only to the "MainWindow" window.

```
<Style  TargetType="local:MainWindow">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF2D2D30" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either set the TargetType to "MainWindow" or set resource reference for Style property.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SetResourceReference(StyleProperty, typeof(Window));
}
```