# Imge to window style background not loading wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, background, styles

I'm new to WPF and after reading some articles about putting an image to my window background I still can't make it work. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
My groceryLog.jpg is set to **Resource** and has "**Copy if newer**" set on **Copy to output**.
My app.xaml

```
<!--Buttons - it works -->
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientStop Color="Cornsilk" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="Aquamarine" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush >
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBorderBrush" Color="Blue"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Name="Border"
                                Background="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundBrush}"
                                BorderBrush="{StaticResource ButtonBorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background"
                                Value="DeepSkyBlue" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background"
                                Value="DeepSkyBlue" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background"
                                Value="DeepSkyBlue" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

<!-- Window - doesn't work -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="images/groceryLog.jpg"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This path would work if the image build action was set as "Content".

If set as "Resource", you need a different path:

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/images/groceryLog.jpg" />
```

Comment: Nope, it's still not working (I changed it to content).

Comment: @DawidDaveKosiński Try setting it as Resource but with the path I gave

Comment: @DawidDaveKosiński Then I suspect that your style isn't applied at all. Have you tried replacing your `ImageBrush` by a `SolidColorBrush`? Is it applied?

Comment: Well, it seems to be the problem. It isn't applied at all. But i don't know what is the problem, because the rest styles work. I could put an example (that works) in the question (in an edit).

Comment: @DawidDaveKosiński I guess you have this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22269709/869621

Comment: thanks it worked. But can I set it to all my windows? It only sets it to the one i define in the "local" parameter in <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:LogIn}">

Comment: @DawidDaveKosiński I think you either have to name your style and apply it explicitly in each window, or make a new base class for all your windows, inheriting from `Window`, and setting the style in the constructor